# How do I add line breaks at the end of lines in a string; to my pattern using preg_match_all? PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to add line breaks using this pattern---- $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m"; but I don't seem to get the results I want. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use s modifier.

```
$pattern = "/^.$pattern.\$/s";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php